# How to compute the SVD of $2\times 2$ matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

What's an efficient algorithm to get the SVD of $2\times 2$ matrices?

I've found papers about doing SVD on $2\times 2$ *triangular* matrices, and I've seen the analytic formula to get the singular values of a $2\times 2$ matrix. But how to use either of these to get the SVD of an arbitrary $2\times 2$ matrix?

Are the general algorithms built on these, or are these just some special cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SVD of a $2\times 2$ matrix has a closed-form formula, which can be worked out by writing the rotation matrices in terms of a single unknown angle each, and then solving for those angles as well as the singular values.

It is worked out [here](http://www.ualberta.ca/~mlipsett/ENGM541/Readings/svd_ellis.pdf), for instance.

Comment: This method always bothered me since it involves a lot of unnecessary trigonometry.

Answer (score 7):

There's a ridiculously easy method to apply the method you already know, starting from your matrix $\mathbf A$. Consider the QR decomposition

$$\mathbf A=\mathbf Q\mathbf R$$

where $\mathbf Q$ is orthogonal and $\mathbf R$ is **upper triangular**. You say you already know how to take the SVD of a triangular matrix:

$$\mathbf R=\mathbf W\mathbf \Sigma\mathbf V^\top$$

where both $\mathbf W$ and $\mathbf V^\top$ are orthogonal and $\mathbf \Sigma$ is diagonal. You know (or at least are supposed to know) that **the product of two orthogonal matrices is again an orthogonal matrix**, so letting $\mathbf U=\mathbf Q\mathbf W$, you should be able to obtain your desired singular value decomposition $\mathbf U\mathbf \Sigma\mathbf V^\top$.

In general, preprocessing your matrix with QR decomposition makes for an easier SVD computation. For a general $m\times n$ matrix, one can do a "thin QR decomposition" (with column pivoting if needed) where $\mathbf Q$ has the same dimensions as the original matrix, and $\mathbf R$ is square and triangular. One can then take the SVD of $\mathbf R$ and then multiply out the orthogonal matrices (and permutation matrices if you did pivoting; remember that permutation matrices are also orthogonal!) to then obtain the singular value decomposition of your original matrix.

---

FWIW, in the $2\times 2$ case, you're charmed, since you can use an appropriately constructed Givens rotation matrix for both the QR and SVD stages. The details should be in e.g. Golub and Van Loan's book.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly straight forward algorithm is to reduce the problem of computing
the SVD of $A$ into finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of
$A^T A:$
$$
\begin{align}
A &= U \Sigma V^T \\
A^T A &= (U \Sigma V^T)^T U \Sigma V^T \\
    &= V \Sigma U^T U \Sigma V^T \\
    &= V \Sigma^2 V^T \\
A^T A V & = V \Sigma^2
\end{align}
$$
The columns of $V$ are the eigenvectors of $A^T A$ and the
squared singular values $\sigma_0^2$ and $\sigma_1^2$ are the eigenvalues
$\lambda_0$ and $\lambda_1.$
Finding the eigenvalues
amounts the finding the roots of a quadratic which are guaranteed
to be real and non-negative:
$$
A^T A= 
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
  a & b \\
  b & c
\end{array}\right] =
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
  A_{00}^2 + A_{10}^2 & A_{00} A_{01} + A_{10} A_{11} \\
  A_{00} A_{01} + A_{10} A_{11} & A_{01}^2 + A_{11}^2
\end{array}\right]
$$
$$
\begin{align}
  q &= \sqrt{(a - c)^2 + 4b^2} \\
  \lambda_0 &= ((a + c) + q)/2,\ \ \  
  \lambda_1 = ((a + c) - q)/2 \\
  \sigma_0 &= \sqrt{\lambda_0},\ \ \ 
  \sigma_1 = \sqrt{\lambda_1}
\end{align}
$$
If $b = 0$ then $V$ is either the identity matrix or skewed symmetric
depending on relative magnitude of the eigenvalues:
$$
V = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
  I, & a \geq c \\
  \left[\begin{array}{cc}
     0 & 1 \\
     1 & 0
  \end{array}\right], & a < c
\end{array}\right.
$$

Otherwise to compute $V$ we first compute the eigenvectors of $A^T A.$  At this point we know $|b| > 0$ and either $a > 0$ or $c > 0.$
For each eigenvector we choose the largest value
in the set $S_i = \{|b|,|\lambda_i - a|,|\lambda_i - c|\}$ to stear
clear of a division by zero:

$$
{\bf e}_i = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\left[\begin{array}{c}
  1 \\
  (\lambda_i - a)/b
\end{array}\right], & 
|b| = \max(S_i) \\
\left[\begin{array}{c}
  b/(\lambda_i - a) \\
   1
\end{array}\right], & 
|\lambda_i - a| = \max(S_i), \\
\left[\begin{array}{c}
  1 \\
  b/(\lambda_i - c)
\end{array}\right], & 
|\lambda_i - c| = \max(S_i).
\end{array}\right.
$$
and normalize
$$
\begin{align}
  \hat{\bf e}_0 &= {\bf e}_0/\| {\bf e}_0 \|,\ \ \ 
  \hat{\bf e}_1 = {\bf e}_1/\| {\bf e}_1 \|
\end{align}.
$$
We then set $V = [\hat{\bf e}_0\ \ \hat{\bf e}_1].$

We then solve $A = U \Sigma V^T$ for $U.$
If $\sigma_0 > \sigma_1 > 0$ then we simply have
$U = A V \Sigma^{-1}.$
If $\sigma_0 = \sigma_1 = 0$ then $U = I$ suffices.
Otherwise $\sigma_0 > \sigma_1 = 0$ and we create the
first column of $U$ as follows:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}
  U_{00} \\
  U_{10}
\end{array}\right] =
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
  \left[\begin{array}{c}
     A_{00}/(\sigma_0 V_{00})\\
     A_{10}/(\sigma_0 V_{00})
  \end{array}\right], & |V_{00}| \geq |V_{10}| \\
 \left[\begin{array}{c}
     A_{10}/(\sigma_0 V_{10})\\
     A_{11}/(\sigma_0 V_{10})
  \end{array}\right], & |V_{00}| < |V_{10}|. \\
\end{array}\right.
$$
The second column is simply made to be orthogonal to the first:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}
  U_{01} \\
  U_{11}
\end{array}\right] =
\left[\begin{array}{c}
  +U_{10} \\
  -U_{00}
\end{array}\right].
$$